# Traversing a hash in order

Tags: perl, hash

I would like to traverse the HASH but one by one. Not in Random ways. Any idea. For example i have hash file something like this...

```
our %HASH = (
'rajesh:1700'  =>  Bangalore,
'rajesh:1730'  =>  Delhi,
'rajesh:1770'  =>  Ranchi,
'rajesh:1780'  =>  Mumbai,
'rajesh:1800'  =>  MYCITY,
'rajesh:1810'  =>  XCF,
);
```

and it should print in same fashion. I tried with following but failed. Any ideas?

```
while ( my $gPort = each %HASH)
{
    print "$gPort\n";
}


for my  $gPort ( keys %HASH )
{
    print "$gPort\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the keys in your question, a simple change to the sort comparator will give your desired output.

```
for my $gPort (sort keys %HASH) {
  print "$gPort => $HASH{$gPort}\n";
}
```

**Note:** the code above assumes all numbers in keys will occur at the same position and have the same length. For instance, a `rajesh:001775` key will come out first rather than between 1770 and 1780.

Comment: its not working in case file contents are having such HASH

rajesh:2130
rajesh:1780
rajesh:2060
rajesh:1810
rajesh:1700

Expected Result is 
rajesh:1700
rajesh:1780
rajesh:1810
rajesh:1810
rajesh:2060
rajesh:2130

Comment: You cannot repeat a key in a hash; the point of a hash is to look up a unique key and retrieve the associated value. If you just want to store ordered pairs, use an array.

Comment: yes we can not.I just gave you the list of keys only. I mean this is a key - "rajesh:1700"

Comment: @RajeshKumar Please edit your question to include samples of different possible key you may encounter in your input.

Comment: Just Edited. Hope this is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort and print out a hash, ordering by VALUE (not keys).

```
for my $gPort (sort { $HASH{$a} <=> $HASH{$b} } keys %HASH) {
  print "$gPort => $HASH{$gPort}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm). In particular, if you set `$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys`, then you would get the dump in sorted order.

As an example:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my %some_hash;

# code to populate hash
[ . . . ]

print Dumper(\%some_hash);
```

Of course, this would work only if you want to plainly dump the hash. If you want the printing to be done in some other format, you would want to just sort the keys and print, like

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %some_hash) {
    print "[KEY]: $key; [VAL]: $some_hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to preserve the insert-order of your elements in your hash then [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Tie-IxHash-1.22/lib/Tie/IxHash.pm) may be the tool for you. It's usage is very simple:

Showing you simple example:

```
    use Tie::IxHash;        
    tie my %days_in => 'Tie::IxHash',
            January   => 31,
            February  => 28,
            March     => 31,
            April     => 30,
            May       => 31,
            June      => 30,
            July      => 31,
            August    => 31,
            September => 30,
            October   => 31,
            November  => 30,
            December  => 31;       


      print join(" ", keys %days_in), "\n";        
    # prints: January February March April May June July August
    # September October November December
```